# Variable length output in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to create an autoencoder in keras with bucketing where the input and the output have different time steps.

```
model = Sequential()

#encoder
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, mask_zero=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=hidden_size, return_sequences=False))

#decoder
model.add(RepeatVector(max_out_length))
model.add(LSTM(units=hidden_size, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')))
```

For the input there is no problem as the network can accept different length inputs as long as the whole batch has the same length. However the problem is with the output size as its determined by the RepeatVector length and there is not easy way to change it.

Is there a solution for such a problem?

Comment: What length do you want? Or what rule should it follow?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "inputs with variable lengths" and "outputs with the same lengths as the inputs", you can do this:

> Warning: this solution must work with batch size = 1
>   You will need to create an external loop and pass each sample as a numpy array with the exact length
>   You cannot use masking in this solution, and the right output depends on the correct length of the input

**This is a working code using Keras + Tensorflow:**

Imports:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as K
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

Custom functions to use in Lambda layers:

```
#this function gets the length from the original input 
#and stores it in the final output of the encoder
def storeLength(x):
    inputTensor = x[0]
    storeInto = x[1] #the final output

    length = K.shape(inputTensor)[1]
    length = K.cast(length,K.floatx())
    length = K.reshape(length,(1,1))

    #will put length as the first element in the final output
    return K.concatenate([length,storeInto])


#this function expands the length of the input in the decoder
def expandLength(x):
    #lenght is the first element in the encoded input
    length = K.cast(x[0,0],'int32') #or int64 if necessary

    #the remaining elements are the actual data to be decoded
    data = x[:,1:]

    #a tensor with shape (length,)
    length = K.ones_like(K.arange(0,length))

    #make both length tensor and data tensor 3D and with paired dimensions 
    length = K.cast(K.reshape(length,(1,-1,1)),K.floatx())
    data = K.reshape(data,(1,1,-1))

    #this automatically repeats the elements based on the paired shapes
    return data*length
```

Creating the models:

I assumed the output is equal to the input, but since you're using an Embedding, I made "num_classes" equal to the number of words.

For this solution, we use a branching, thus I had to use the functional API `Model`. Which will be way better later, because you will want to train with `autoencoder.train_on_batch` and then just encode with `encoder.predict()` or just decode with `decoder.predict()`.

```
vocab_size = 100
embedding_size = 7
num_class=vocab_size
hidden_size = 3

#encoder
inputs = Input(batch_shape = (1,None))
outputs = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size)(inputs)
outputs = LSTM(units=hidden_size, return_sequences=False)(outputs)
outputs = Lambda(storeLength)([inputs,outputs])
encoder = Model(inputs,outputs)

#decoder
inputs = Input(batch_shape=(1,hidden_size+1))
outputs = Lambda(expandLength)(inputs)
outputs = LSTM(units=hidden_size, return_sequences=True)(outputs)
outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(num_class, activation='softmax'))(outputs)
decoder = Model(inputs,outputs)

#autoencoder
inputs = Input(batch_shape=(1,None))
outputs = encoder(inputs)
outputs = decoder(outputs)
autoencoder = Model(inputs,outputs)

#see each model's shapes 
encoder.summary()
decoder.summary()
autoencoder.summary()
```

Just an example with fake data and the method that should be used for training:

```
inputData = []
outputData = []
for i in range(7,10):
    inp = np.arange(i).reshape((1,i))
    inputData.append(inp)

    outputData.append(to_categorical(inp,num_class))

autoencoder.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')

for epoch in range(1):
    for inputSample,outputSample in zip(inputData,outputData):

        print(inputSample.shape,outputSample.shape)
        autoencoder.train_on_batch(inputSample,outputSample)

for inputSample in inputData:
    print(autoencoder.predict(inputSample).shape)
```

Comment: To clarify, does the encoder you proposed above create a fixed feature vector that is of constant length regardless of the input length?

Comment: Exactly. The solution is not "great" because of the batch size limitation, though. But you could spend some time detecting the length of padded sequences with summing non-mask comparisons.

Comment: What if you have a fixed-length input and a variable-length output?